# File 'MakePri.exe' not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2013 for most of my development needs. I installed Visual Studio 2015 (Professional) and started looking at the Universal Windows app. I created a blank app and built it. It failed with the following error:

```
File 'MakePri.exe' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12560&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=UAP&o2=10.0.10586.0 for more information.    App4    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets
```

I could not make anything out of it as other apps (eg: web sites, Classic Desktop) are building fine. I looked up and found pointers to SDK path. I went into options and turned on MSBuild project build output to diagnostic. Here is the log from the Output window. I found where it's failing but I'm unable to figure out how to fix it. The output is very detailed and exceeds the character limits here. But, here is the part that has the fail info.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(892,5): error APPX1639: File 'MakePri.exe' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12560&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=UAP&o2=10.0.10586.0 for more information.
1>Done executing task "GetSdkFileFullPath" -- FAILED. (TaskId:50)
1>Done building target "_GetSdkToolPaths" in project "App4.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:78)
```

On my machine, I do not have a "Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(892,5)" file in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\

How can I fix this error? Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you installed the Windows 10 SDK? https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk Also target the solution to Build 10586

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, Windows 10 SDK was installed (both 10586 and 10240 are) and the target is set to 10586. I also tried with 10240 as target. Same error.

Comment: try to repair VS2015

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing Ionic/Cordova application and have this problem with building appx for windows.

For me worked reinstalling Windows SDK 10.0.14393.33 from SDKSETUP.EXE http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/3/B/63BADCE0-F2E6-44BD-B2F9-60F5F073038E/standalonesdk/SDKSETUP.EXE

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing entry of WindowsSdkDir from system's environment variables.

My *WindowsSdkDir* entry was pointing to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A*

[image]